# I am trying to create two activities with intents but getting the error "exception dispatching finished signal...."

Tags: android

If anyone could explain me why I am getting this error, and how to rectify it.

This is the second activity

```
public class Result_activity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
     super.onCreate(bundle);

     setContentView(R.layout.result_activity);
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     String inputString = extras.getString("yourkey");
     TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     view.setText(inputString);
  }

  @Override
  public void finish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result_value);
    String string = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("returnkey", string);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.finish();
  }
}
```

This is my main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   // constant to determine which sub-activity returns
   private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String string = text.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Result_activity.class);
        i.putExtra("yourkey", string);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
              if (data.hasExtra("returnkey")) {
                  String result = data.getExtras().getString("returnkey");
              if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace? I'm guessing one of the lines in finish() is crashing?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

does not specify any action or class.

In your main activity you specified an intent with a class which is the correct way :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Result_activity.class);
```